# Perl regex substitute from hash

Tags: regex, perl

Is there an efficient way to substitute a bunch a strings using values from a Perl hash?

For example,

```
$regex{foo} = "bar";
$regex{hello} = "world";
$regex{python} = "perl";

open(F, "myfile.txt");
while (<F>) {
      foreach $key (keys %regex) {
            s/$key/$regex{$key}/g;
      }
}
close(F);
```

Is there a way to accomplish the above in Perl?

Comment: If all else fails, try `eval` (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)

Comment: @Nick, That the worse possible advice, as far as I'm concerned. How could it possibly help!?

Comment: Substituting variables is not possible anywhere in perl code -- `eval` gives you the ability to expand variables within a string and then execute that string as perl code, e.g. eval "s/$key/$regex{$key}/g"

Comment: @Nick, Again, that makes things worse. `s///` already interpolates.

Comment: Ok -- see my answer based on the "dreaded" `eval`

Answer (score 7):

First question: are you sure that what you have is *inefficient*?

Second, the most obvious next step would be to pull everything into a single regex:

```
my $check = join '|', keys %regex;
```

And then you can do the substitution as:

```
s/($check)/$regex{$1}/g;
```

This can still be "slow" with sufficient overlap of the keys where the regex engine has to recheck the same letters constantly.  You can possibly use something like [Regexp::Optimizer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aOptimizer) to eliminate the overlap.  But the cost of optimising may be more than the cost of just doing everything, depending on how many changes (key/values in your hash) and how many lines you're modifying.  Premature optimisation-- !

Note that, of course, your example code isn't doing anything with the text after the substitution.  It won't modify the file in-place, so I'm assuming you're handling that separately.

Answer (score 4):

Define a regexp that matches any of the keys.

```
$regex = join("|", map {quotemeta} keys %regex);
```

Replace any match of `$regex` by `$regex{$1}`.

```
s/($regex)/$regex{$1}/go;
```

Omit the `o` modifier if `$regex` changes during the execution of the program.

Note that if there are keys that are a prefix of another key (e.g. `f` and `foo`), whichever comes first in the joined regexp will be seen as a match (e.g. `f|foo` matches `f` but `foo|f` matches `foo` in `foobar`). If that can happen, you may need to sort `keys %regex` according to which match you want to win. (Thanks to [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) for pointing this out.)

Comment: If you have keys like abc and abcd, it's important to sort by decreasing length:  `map {quotemeta} sort { length($b)<=>length($a) } keys %regex`

Comment: @ysth Thanks, I'd never realized that Perl had a leftmost match policy, not longest match!

Answer (score 4):

To prove the point of `eval` and also out of curiosity, I ran some tests with the OP's code vs. the `$regex{$1}` approach vs. the `eval` approach.

First off, there seems to be little value in cramming every possible token in a `(token|token|...)` match expression. Perl needs to check against all tokens at once -- it is debatable how much more efficient this is than simply checking every token at a time and doing the replacement with a hardcoded value.

Secondly, doing `$regex{$1}` means the hashmap key is extracted on every match.

Anyway, here are some numbers (ran this on strawberry 5.12, with a 4MB file of 100K lines):

1. The `$regex{$1}` approach takes **6 seconds** (5 seconds with /go instead of /g)
2. The `tie` approach takes **10 seconds**
3. The OP approach takes **a bit under 1 second** (with /go instead of /g)
4. The `eval` approach takes **less than 1 second** (faster than the OP code)

This is the `eval` approach:

```
$regex{foo} = "bar";
$regex{hello} = "world";
$regex{python} = "perl";
$regex{bartender} = "barista";

$s = <<HEADER;
\$start = time;
open(F, "myfile.txt");
while (<F>) {
HEADER

foreach $key (keys %regex) {
   $s .= "s/$key/$regex{$key}\/go;\n"
}

$s .= <<FOOTER;
print \$_;
}
close(F);
print STDERR "Elapsed time (eval.pl): " . (time - \$start) . "\r\n";
FOOTER

eval $s;
```

Comment: That's interesting, I wouldn't have expected the `$regex{$1}` approach to be so slow. Does using `Regexp::Optimizer` make a difference? How do the timings change depending on the number of keys?

Comment: @Giles, very good questions, obviously -- not to mention the platform (windows) and perl distribution might make a difference. Any help on this sort of profiling is more than welcome -- it would also be good to hear something from the OP - which of these approaches is the most efficient on his/her environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -e '                                                         \
          my %replace =  (foo=>bar, hello=>world, python=>perl);  \
          my $find    =  join "|", sort keys %replace;            \
          my $str     =  "foo,hello,python";                      \
          $str        =~ s/($find)/$replace{$1}/g;                \
          print "$str\n\n";                                       \
        '
```

Something you may want to consider is not going line-by-line of the file, but instead processing the whole file at once and use the `/s` modifier on your regex for single-line mode.

Answer (score 1):

What you have works as is, so it's not clear what your request is.

One catch: The code you posted may have problems with double substitutions depending on the contents of `%regex` and/or `$_`. For example,

```
my %regex = (
   foo => 'bar',
   bar => 'foo',
);
```

The solution is to move the foreach into the pattern, so to speak.

```
my $pat =
   join '|',
    map quotemeta,  # Convert text to regex patterns.
     keys %regex;

my $re = qr/$pat/;  # Precompile for efficiency.

my $qfn = 'myfile.txt'
open(my $fh, '<', $qfn) or die "open: $qfn: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
   s/($re)/$regex{$1}/g;
   ... do something with $_ ...
}
```

Comment: the while cycle is not the solution! Where do you write?

Comment: @cirne100, you specify what you wanted to do with the edited text. If you want to write it somewhere, go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

## The begin:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Tie::File;

my %tr=(   'foo' => 'bar',
            #(...)
        );
my $r =join("|", map {quotemeta} keys %tr);
$r=qr|$r|;
```

## with big files use:

```
tie my @array,"Tie::File",$ARGV[0] || die;
for (@array) { 
    s/($r)/$tr{$1}/g;
}
untie @array;
```

## with small files use:

```
open my $fh,'<',$ARGV[0] || die;
local $/ = undef;
my $t=<$fh>;
close $fh;
$t=~s/($r)/$tr{$1}/g;
open $fh,'>',$ARGV[0] || die;
print $fh $t;
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so I'm surprised no one has yet suggested the obvious: pre-compile each of the regexps (i.e. the hash keys).

```
$regex{qr/foo/} = 'bar';
$regex{qr/hello/} = 'world';
$regex{qr/python/} = 'perl';

open(F, "myfile.txt");
while (<F>) {
      foreach $key (keys %regex) {
            s/$key/$regex{$key}/g;
      }
}
close(F);
```

or for (IMO) greater readability:

```
%regex = (
    qr/foo/    => 'bar',
    qr/hello/  => 'world',
    qr/python/ => 'perl',
);
```

If you know that there can only be one possible match per input line then skipping the remaining regexps with `last` after a successful match will also help if there are a lot of keys.  e.g. inside the `for` loop:

```
s/$key/$regex{$key}/g && last;
```