# Perl substitution - lookup table issue

Tags: regex, perl, hashtable, lookup, substitution

I have a ~35MB KML file where all the placemarks are named "kml1234" and the like. I want to replace the name with a readable string like "Area 9987" and I have the lookup table. I found a snippet of perl here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6435950) and it worked for the majority of the placemarks. However, I found that it failed in specific cases. Here is the code.

```
$repl{kml1} = "Area A";
$repl{kml12} = "Area B";
$repl{kml123} = "Area C";
$repl{kml69} = "Area D";
$repl{kml4458} = "Area E";

$s = <<HEADER;
\$start = time;
open(F, "input.txt");
open(OUTPUT, ">output.txt");
while (<F>) {
HEADER

foreach $key (keys %repl) {
   $s .= "s/$key/$repl{$key}\/;\n"
}

$s .= <<FOOTER;
print \$_;
}
close(F);
close(OUTPUT);
print "Elapsed time (eval.pl): " . (time - \$start) . "\r\n";
FOOTER

eval $s;
```

I've tested this in isolation using a test string (put into input.txt):

```
<Placemark id="kml123">
```

The expected result from this is:

```
<Placemark id="Area C">
```

However, if I run the script again with the same input (kml123), I get any one of the 3 results below:

```
<Placemark id="Area A23">
<Placemark id="Area B3">
<Placemark id="Area C">
```

It seems that the subsititution is somehow truncating $key to only kml1 or kml12 sometimes? I notice that I never get "Area D" or "Area E" which is expected, and I suspect that it is because they do are not similar enough to kml123, just the first 3. Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main problem was mentioned already in @ahjohnston25's answer, but you took over so ugly code with evaling and fuzzy stuff, so I made it a bit simpler and cleaner:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings; use autodie;

my %repl = (
  "kml1" => "Area A",
  "kml12" => "Area B",
  "kml123" => "Area C",
  "kml69" => "Area D",
  "kml4458" => "Area E",
);

open( my $F, '<', "input.txt" );
open( my $OUTPUT, '>', "output.txt" );

while ( <$F> ) {
  foreach my $key ( sort keys %repl ) {
     s/\b$key\b/$repl{$key}/g;
  }
  print $OUTPUT $_; 
}

close( $F );
close( $OUTPUT );
```

I hope in this form it is much easier to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The core of this program uses Perl's regular expressions. The problem is that to Perl `kml1` as a search string (the first part of your `s///` expression) matches `kml123`. If you change your search/replace to the following:

```
s/"$key">$/"$repl{$key}"/;
```

It will work as it will only match if the exact pattern is surrounded in quotation marks.

It's a bit think, but reading [this page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) on regular expressions will make you a master at them. Playing games like [regex golf](https://regex.alf.nu/) will also help you improve your skills and solve this problems more efficiently.